# Orbeon 4.7 bug in xforms:label with html?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We have an xforms:select1/xforms:itemset with items that have HTML markup on the labels:

```
<xforms:select ref="@labels" appearance="full" class="inline">
    <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('issue-labels-instance')/label">
        <xforms:label>
            <xhtml:div class="labelouterboxitem" title="{desc[1]/text()}">
                <xhtml:div style="background-color:{@color}; display: inline; padding-left: 10px; margin: -3px;">&#160;</xhtml:div>
                <xhtml:div style="background-color: white;display: inline;">
                    <xforms:output ref="concat('&#160;(',@code,')&#160;',@name,'&#160;')"/>
                </xhtml:div>
            </xhtml:div>
        </xforms:label>
        <xforms:value ref="@code"/>
    </xforms:itemset>
</xforms:select>
```

This rendered fine under Orbeon 3.9. Under Orbeon 4.7 however it renders fine initially, but when the underlying itemset changes or when the xforms:select is under an xforms:group that becomes visible (based on user interaction) the HTML tags are rendered as text.

[image]

I could not find that this was fixed since Orbeon 4.7. Can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I can't reproduce this. [Here is the example](https://gist.github.com/avernet/704e5f83dbf359c7e4be) I used.

And this is [working for me](https://saucelabs.com/tests/7e72471db2694822a52d0d50f0012b21); the HTML shows even if the containing group isn't relevant at first, and then the content updates properly.

I'd recommend you check this example works for you, and if it does, that you modify it to reproduce the issue you're seeing, and submit that in another question, or updating this question.